# Node/npm: ORM library like Mongoose for BigQuery

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, orm, node-orm2

I am working on a Nodejs application, where data source had been migrated to BigQuery from MongoDb.

We are using `mongoose` as a ORM library to define Schema for all Entity Tables in current system.

Is there any library module for `BigQuery` to achieve similar Schema definitions in Node JS?

Answer (score 0):

Schema definition of `mongoose` and `BigQuery` in Node.js are completely different from each other.

`moongoose` uses a *schema class* for the creation and definition of the schema. You may refer to this [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) for more details.

On the other hand, `BigQuery` uses *dictionary* in defining the schema and then passes it as an attribute. You may refer to this [BigQuery Node.js Sample Code Implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/6438df629e9adb707338bd53959c7c10e0ae2936/samples/createTable.js) for more details.

Therefore, this is a limitation of BigQuery API for Node.js.